# React.useState, will not update. How do I perform a instant update of React useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm setting up a react useContext to share user's data such as the user's name and the login status etc... I make a request to the server every time a user refreshes the app to verify that if they have a valid token, the user can then be logged in. Great, but one problem I keep on running into with react is knowing how to get an instant update of useState, as this is needing to be updated as soon as the user is verified.

I've read that you have to create a new object so that React knows it's a new object and then it'll trigger a re-render... Just about every combination I can think of I've tried. Can someone please clarify for me how it's done?

Option 1:

```
   setUser(prev => {
    return { ...prev, ...newObj }
   })
```

Option 2:

```
   setUser({ ...newObj })
```

Can someone please give me the proper way to get a instant update to the React useState.

Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useReadCookie } from "../hooks/cookies";
import UserContext from "./user-context";

const UserContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const readCookie = useReadCookie;

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: null,
    userID: null,
    token: null,
    permissions: null,
    loginStatus: false,
    checkLoginStatusReady: false,
  });


  const loginStatus = async () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, rej) => {
      // So we'll reach out to the server and check to see if the
      // User is logged in

      const token = readCookie("token");

      if (token && token.length === 174) {
        // send a request to see if this is a valid user
        const req = await fetch("/api/checkLoginStatus.php");

        const res = await req.json();

        // console.log(res);
        handleLogUserIn(res);
      }

      console.log(user, "The state variable");
      resolve();
    });
  };

  const handleLogUserIn = (res) => {
    if (res.success === true) {
      const userObj = {
        name: res.name,
        userID: res.userID,
        token: res.token,
        permissions: res.permissions,
        loginStatus: true,
        checkLoginStatusReady: true,
      };

      console.log(userObj, "the user variable");

      setUser({ ...userObj });
    }
    else {
      console.log("Not going here");
      const userObj = {
        name: null,
        userID: null,
        token: null,
        permissions: null,
        loginStatus: false,
        checkLoginStatusReady: true,
      };
      setUser({ ...userObj });
    }
  };

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        username: user.username,
        userID: user.userID,
        token: user.token,
        permissions: user.permissions,
        loginStatus: user.loginStatus,
        checkLoginStatusReady: loginStatus,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContextProvider;
```

Comment: What do you mean by an "instant update"? What you've shown seems like it would update the state just fine, what problem do you have with them?

Comment: Meaning whenever I go to my app component that is being shared with useContext and I try and read the user object that is being updated by useState it's showing the initial value of the state... Meaning it's not yet updated and it's not instantly available... For example, if I were to set const name = "jon" and right after that line console.log(name) it'll come back as jon.

Comment: `setUser(newObj)` is the correct way. Because newObj is a new object fetched from the API.

Comment: @JonW Unfortunately that is not how state works in react, when state is updated it triggers an update and the next time you component is called it will get the new state. The update shouldn't take that long though, can you add examples of why is this process not quick enough for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use useEffect for listening to the state update
example if using

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
 username : "",
 status : "",
})

useEffect(() => {
   setState({
...state, 
username : state.username,
status : "active,
})
},[state])
```

or if using context :
On parent provider.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const UserContext = React.createContext({
  username: "",
  status: "active",
  setUser: () => {}
})

export const UserContextProvider = (props) => {

  const setUser = (param) => {
    setState({...state, username: param.username, status: param.status})
  }

  const initState = {
   username: "",
   status: "active",
   setUser: () => {}
  } 

  const [state, setState] = useState(initState)

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={state}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

On Component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import provider from './provider'

function Component() {

  const context = useContext(provider.UserContext)
  const onClick = () => {
    // do hit api
    if(token){
      state.setUser({username : "a", status:"inactive"})
    }
  }

  return (
    <provider.UserContextProvider>
      <buttin onClick={onClick}></button>
        <div>username : {state.username}</div>
        <div>status : {state.status}</div>
    </provider.UserContextProvider>
  )
}
```